# Java compiler: How can two methods with the same name and different signatures match a method call?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have this class called `Container`:

```
public class Container {

    private final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String name, Object value) {
        map.put(name, value);
    }

    public Container with(String name, Object value) {
        put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    public Object get(String name) {
        return map.get(name);
    }

    public <R> R get(String name, Function<Object, R> mapper) {

        Object value = get(name);

        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }

        return mapper
            .apply(value);
    }

    public <R> R get(String name, Class<R> type) {

        Object value = get(name);

        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }

        if (type.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
            return type
                .cast(value);
        }

        throw new ClassCastException(String
            .format("%s -> %s", value.getClass(), type));
    }
}
```

and the class called `Token`:

```
public class Token {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Token withValue(String value) {
        setValue(value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

and finally a test class for the `Token` class

```
public class TokenTest {

    @Test
    public void verifyToken() {
        verify("bar", new Token()
            .withValue("bar"));
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyContainer() {
        Container tokens = new Container()
            .with("foo", "bar")
            .with("baz", "bat");

        verify("bar", tokens.get("foo", String.class));
        verify("bat", tokens.get("baz", String::valueOf));  // line 21
    }

    private void verify(String expected, String actual) {
        verify(expected, new Token()
            .withValue(actual));
    }

    private void verify(String expected, Token actual) {
        Assert
            .assertEquals(expected, actual.getValue());
    }
}
```

The test compiles and runs just fine in eclipse.

When building on the commad line

```
mvn clean test
```

a compile error is raised:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project ambiguous: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/data/projects/java/ambiguous/src/test/java/ambiguous/TokenTest.java:[21,9] reference to verify is ambiguous
[ERROR]   both method verify(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in ambiguous.TokenTest and method verify(java.lang.String,ambiguous.Token) in ambiguous.TokenTest match
```

The compilation also fails when I change line `21` to one of

```
verify("bat", tokens.get("baz", e -> String.valueOf(e)));
verify("bat", tokens.get("baz", e -> e.toString));
```

When I change the line to one of

```
verify("bat", tokens.get("baz", String.class));
verify("bat", tokens.get("baz", Object::toString));
```

compilation is successful.

I cannot undestand why this compiliation error is raised.

I came across the follwong links [boxing and unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918807/ambiguous-compilation-error-with-maven-and-apache-utils), [multiple generic types and intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815771/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-methods-caused-by-intersection-types-in-java-generics) and this [eclipse compiler bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461539) but I still cannot relate to the mentioned causes.

My question is, what makes the compiler think that both signatures of the `verify` method are matching when the mapper `String::valueOf` is passed to the `get` method?

For compilation the following jdk is used (with maven and gradle):

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_201-1-ojdkbuild"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-1-ojdkbuild-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: None of the variants work with IntelliJ using Java 12 for me at least. The relevant part if the type bound to the method instead of the class `<R>` while you perform `get`.

Comment: [related1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276988/method-reference-is-ambiguous-for-thread-sleep/47280995#47280995) and [related2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715030/1059372).... this is like a recursion here - it _might_ be obvious to you, but not the compiler. _In general_ overloads and poly expressions in form of lambdas are tricky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [JLS §15.12.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2):

> An argument expression is considered *pertinent to applicability* for a
>   potentially applicable method `m` unless it has one of the following
>   forms:
>
> - An implicitly typed lambda expression<sup>1</sup>.
> - An inexact method reference expression<sup>2</sup>.
> - [...]

Therefore:

```
verify("bar", tokens.get("foo", e -> String.valueOf(e)));
```

an implicitly typed lambda expression `e -> String.valueOf(e)` is skipped from the applicability check during overload resolution - both `verify(...)` methods become applicable - hence the ambiguity.

In comparison, here are some examples that will work, because the types are specified explicitly:

```
verify("bar", tokens.get("foo", (Function<Object, String>) e -> String.valueOf(e)));

verify("bar", tokens.get("foo", (Function<Object, String>) String::valueOf));
```

---

<sup>1 - An implicitly typed lambda expression is a lambda expression, where the types of all its formal parameters are inferred.</sup>
<sup>2 - An inexact method reference - one with multiple overloads.</sup>

Comment: Making the lambda explicitly typed with `(Object e) -> String.valueOf(e))` resolves the compile error. On the other hand, does this behaviour imply that the compiler is thinking that the lambda might also return `Token`?

Comment: @A4L No, the lambda expression is just skipped from the check.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple implementations of `String.valueOf(...)` with different arguments. The compiler does not know which one you want to call. The compiler is not capable of seeing that all the possible methods actually return a `String` and therefore it does not really matter which method is called. Since the compiler does not know what the return type will be it cannot infer a proper `Function<...,...>` as the type of the expression and it therefore cannot understand wether you will have a `Function` or something else at hand and therefore cannot tell if you want to call the `get` method with a `Function` or a `Class`.

---

If you instead of `String::valueOf` use `e -> String.valueOf(e)` then the compiler can infer a little more but it will still not understand that you will always return a `String` and will therefore interpret it as `Function<Object, Object>` which your `verify` method then has a problem with.

---

`e -> e.toString` I do not understand fully, I do not see why the compiler is incapable of inferring `String` as a return type here. It infers `Object` and does the exact same thing as in the previous case. If you split the operation into

```
String s = tokens.get("baz", e -> e.toString());
verify("bat", s);  // line 21
```

then it works because the compiler can infer the generic `R` from the type of `s`. The same way it works by explicitly specifying `R`:

```
verify("bat", tokens.<String>get("baz", e -> e.toString()));  // line 21
```

---

`String.class` the compiler easily understands that you want to call the `get(Class)` method.

---

`Object::toString` makes sense to work since the compiler knows this will be a `Function<Object, String>`.

Comment: `The compiler is not capable of seeing that all the possible methods actually return a String` But why is that?

Comment: @A4L I do not know, but there are lots of things compilers do not do, some things they *could* do but intentionally don't vs. other things that are practically impossible. It may be that the answer by Oleksandr is actually more correct in terms of actually referencing JLS, mine is just interpretation and speaking from experience.